# jquery table dnd plugin with gridview - on drop event never works

Tags: jquery, .net

I am using asp.net (3.5). I have GridView and I need to use Drag&Drop for purpose to reorder items (table rows) and save new order to db.

I have found out that I can use jquery.tablednd plugin for this purpose.

DnD functionality really works for me, but I cannot reorder items and save in db, because ON DROP never works for me.

I have tried to copy different examples I found in web, but ondrop never works for me. I have created new file to do tests (my original page uses masterpage). 
I have included ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager , but I have also tried it with asp:ScriptManager.
DropAndDrag is working, but ON DROP event is never called. OnDragStart event is called successfully.
Please, have a look to my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="News.aspx.cs" Inherits="Tutelaconnect.News" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.isocra.com/articles/jquery.tablednd.js" type="text/javascript">  
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= GridViewSample.ClientID %>").tableDnD({
            onDrop: function (table, row) {
                alert('1');                    ///// THIS NEVER HAPPEN
            },
            onDragStart: function (table, row) {
                // alert('2');  //// THIS HAPPENS
            }
        });
    });        
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
 <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
<div id="debugArea">
</div>
<div class="tableDemo">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridViewSample" runat="server" AutoGenerateSelectButton="false"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="800px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="C">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxC" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("C") %>' Width="50px" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10em" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="A">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelA" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("A") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="30em" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am really stuck. Do not know how to continue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution here: http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/comment-page-15/#comment-3460

Basically, each row in your table needs an Id, you can use code like this to give them one:

```
var i = 0;
$("#<%= GridViewSample.ClientID %>").find('tr').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('id', i++);
});
```

I placed this code right before: `$("#<%= GridViewSample.ClientID %>").tableDnD` and was able to get the `alert(1);` box displaying each time I dropped a row.

Comment: Thank you!  This tidbit helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the triggering function of `on drop` in the **js file** whether it is defined or not 
then you will be able to find where the error lies.